# C# Populate TreeView with FTP Server Directories

Tags: c#, ftp

I have searched the web, and is new to this still. Please have some patience with me.

What I want to do is this: 
- I have a TreeView called "treeTO".
- I connect to my FTP Server and I want to populate everything here (the directories, sub directories, and the files, whatever it may be) in the treeview.
- This is my code I have so far:

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + ActiveServer.Server + "/");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ActiveServer.UserName, ActiveServer.Password);
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
```

-This returns me the following text: Logs, Data, and WwwRoot.

I struggle to add this to the treeview and then loop through the folders to add everything to the treeview.

Comment: which technologie do you use? ASP.NET, WPF, WinForms? and which TreeView?

Comment: Its WinForms, and its the normal TreeView with plus signs next to the nodes

Comment: ok I will have a look, and will post an Answer ;-)

Comment: Got it working , I´ve tested this with my FTP-Server and it worked fine! Maybe you need to tweak it a little bit for your UseCase!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So here´s my working Solution for you!

Of course you have to replace the Value of "root" with the rootURL of your FTP-Server and in the Method GetWebRequest() replace "username" and "password" with your Credentials!

You need this Class to Hold Details

```
public class FTPListDetail
{
        public bool IsDirectory
        {
            get
            {
                return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Dir) && Dir.ToLower().Equals("d");
            }
        }
        internal string Dir { get; set; }
        public string Permission { get; set; }
        public string Filecode { get; set; }
        public string Owner { get; set; }
        public string Group { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string FullPath { get; set; }
}
```

and here is the Code-Behind for your WinForm-App

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var root = "ftp://ftp.yourFTPServer.at";

    treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
    treeView1.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(root, "root"));
}

private TreeNode CreateDirectoryNode(string path, string name)
{
    var directoryNode = new TreeNode(name);
    var directoryListing = GetDirectoryListing(path);

    var directories = directoryListing.Where(d => d.IsDirectory);
    var files = directoryListing.Where(d => !d.IsDirectory);

    foreach (var dir in directories)
    {
        directoryNode.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(dir.FullPath, dir.Name));
    }
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
            directoryNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(file.Name));
    }
    return directoryNode;
}

public IEnumerable<FTPListDetail> GetDirectoryListing(string rootUri)
{
    var CurrentRemoteDirectory = rootUri;
    var result = new StringBuilder();
    var request = GetWebRequest(WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails, CurrentRemoteDirectory);
    using (var response = request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            while (line != null)
            {
                result.Append(line);
                result.Append("\n");
                line = reader.ReadLine();
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.ToString()))
            {
                return new List<FTPListDetail>();
            }
            result.Remove(result.ToString().LastIndexOf("\n"), 1);
            var results = result.ToString().Split('\n');
            string regex =
                @"^" +               //# Start of line
                @"(?<dir>[\-ld])" +          //# File size          
                @"(?<permission>[\-rwx]{9})" +            //# Whitespace          \n
                @"\s+" +            //# Whitespace          \n
                @"(?<filecode>\d+)" +
                @"\s+" +            //# Whitespace          \n
                @"(?<owner>\w+)" +
                @"\s+" +            //# Whitespace          \n
                @"(?<group>\w+)" +
                @"\s+" +            //# Whitespace          \n
                @"(?<size>\d+)" +
                @"\s+" +            //# Whitespace          \n
                @"(?<month>\w{3})" +          //# Month (3 letters)   \n
                @"\s+" +            //# Whitespace          \n
                @"(?<day>\d{1,2})" +        //# Day (1 or 2 digits) \n
                @"\s+" +            //# Whitespace          \n
                @"(?<timeyear>[\d:]{4,5})" +     //# Time or year        \n
                @"\s+" +            //# Whitespace          \n
                @"(?<filename>(.*))" +            //# Filename            \n
                @"$";                //# End of line

            var myresult = new List<FTPListDetail>();
            foreach (var parsed in results)
            {
                var split = new Regex(regex)
                    .Match(parsed);
                var dir = split.Groups["dir"].ToString();
                var permission = split.Groups["permission"].ToString();
                var filecode = split.Groups["filecode"].ToString();
                var owner = split.Groups["owner"].ToString();
                var group = split.Groups["group"].ToString();
                var filename = split.Groups["filename"].ToString();
                myresult.Add(new FTPListDetail()
                {
                    Dir = dir,
                    Filecode = filecode,
                    Group = group,
                    FullPath = CurrentRemoteDirectory + "/" + filename,
                    Name = filename,
                    Owner = owner,
                    Permission = permission,
                });
            };
            return myresult;
        }
    }
}

private FtpWebRequest GetWebRequest(string method, string uri)
{
    Uri serverUri = new Uri(uri);
    if (serverUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeFtp)
    {
        return null;
    }
    var reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(serverUri);
    reqFTP.Method = method;
    reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
    reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("yourUser", "yourPassword");
    reqFTP.Proxy = null;
    reqFTP.KeepAlive = false;
    reqFTP.UsePassive = false;
    return reqFTP;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a reason why no FTP client on the planet preemptively populates a treeview on an FTP server or displays file icons in the treeview. Either one of these will take FOREVER.

What you'll need to do is rethink how you are doing this. When you first connect you are going to want to just populate the tree up until the initial dir and then the initial directory. You do NOT want to put files in your tree view because that will also eat up too much memory in many real world situations. Just add folders (and use the same ICON for >99% of those).

This is what it should look like when you first log in:

```
/
-home
 -joe
  -public_html
  -docs
  -uploads
```

Notice that, '/' and 'home' are not fully read at this point, we just insert them as placeholders for the user to click on. After that, you just want to add the directories in the clicked folder which aren't there each time the users clicks a folder.

This strategy is going to make life a million times easier. Even if you want to try those more complicated ways to handle this you'll want to start out with the basics.

Answer (score 0):

I used this class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Backup_service
{
    internal class Ftp_Client
    {
        //поля
        //поле для хранения имени фтп-сервера
        private string _Host;

        //поле для хранения логина
        private string _UserName;

        //поле для хранения пароля
        private string _Password;

        //объект для запроса данных
        private FtpWebRequest ftpRequest;

        //объект для получения данных
        private FtpWebResponse ftpResponse;

        //флаг использования SSL
        private bool _UseSSL = false;

        //фтп-сервер
        public string Host
        {
            get
            {
                return _Host;
            }
            set
            {
                _Host = value;
            }
        }

        //логин
        public string UserName
        {
            get
            {
                return _UserName;
            }
            set
            {
                _UserName = value;
            }
        }

        //пароль
        public string Password
        {
            get
            {
                return _Password;
            }
            set
            {
                _Password = value;
            }
        }

        //Для установки SSL-чтобы данные нельзя было перехватить
        public bool UseSSL
        {
            get
            {
                return _UseSSL;
            }
            set
            {
                _UseSSL = value;
            }
        }

        //Реализеум команду LIST для получения подробного списока файлов на FTP-сервере
        public FileStruct[] ListDirectory(string path)
        {
            if (path == null || path == "")
            {
                path = "/";
            }
            //Создаем объект запроса
            ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + _Host + path);
            //логин и пароль
            ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_UserName, _Password);
            //команда фтп LIST
            ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;

            ftpRequest.EnableSsl = _UseSSL;
            //Получаем входящий поток
            ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();

            //переменная для хранения всей полученной информации
            string content = "";

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ftpResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
            content = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
            ftpResponse.Close();

            DirectoryListParser parser = new DirectoryListParser(content);
            return parser.FullListing;
        }

        //метод протокола FTP RETR для загрузки файла с FTP-сервера
        public void DownloadFile(string path, string currentfileName)
        {
            ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + _Host + path);

            ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_UserName, _Password);
            //команда фтп RETR
            ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

            ftpRequest.EnableSsl = _UseSSL;
            //Файлы будут копироваться в кталог программы
            if (!Directory.Exists(currentfileName))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(currentfileName);
            }
            FileStream downloadedFile = new FileStream(currentfileName + @"\" + path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf('/') + 1), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

            ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
            //Получаем входящий поток
            Stream responseStream = ftpResponse.GetResponseStream();

            //Буфер для считываемых данных
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int size = 0;

            while ((size = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024)) > 0)
            {
                downloadedFile.Write(buffer, 0, size);
            }
            ftpResponse.Close();
            downloadedFile.Close();
            responseStream.Close();
        }

        //метод протокола FTP STOR для загрузки файла на FTP-сервер
        public void UploadFile(string path, string fileName)
        {
            //для имени файла
            string shortName = fileName.Remove(0, fileName.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);

            FileStream uploadedFile = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

            ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + _Host + path + shortName);
            ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_UserName, _Password);
            ftpRequest.EnableSsl = _UseSSL;
            ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

            //Буфер для загружаемых данных
            byte[] file_to_bytes = new byte[uploadedFile.Length];
            //Считываем данные в буфер
            uploadedFile.Read(file_to_bytes, 0, file_to_bytes.Length);

            uploadedFile.Close();

            //Поток для загрузки файла
            Stream writer = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream();

            writer.Write(file_to_bytes, 0, file_to_bytes.Length);
            writer.Close();
        }

        //метод протокола FTP DELE для удаления файла с FTP-сервера
        public void DeleteFile(string path)
        {
            ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + _Host + path);
            ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_UserName, _Password);
            ftpRequest.EnableSsl = _UseSSL;
            ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile;

            FtpWebResponse ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
            ftpResponse.Close();
        }

        //метод протокола FTP MKD для создания каталога на FTP-сервере
        public void CreateDirectory(string path, string folderName)
        {
            FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + _Host + path + folderName);

            ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_UserName, _Password);
            ftpRequest.EnableSsl = _UseSSL;
            ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;

            FtpWebResponse ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
            ftpResponse.Close();
        }

        //метод протокола FTP RMD для удаления каталога с FTP-сервера
        public void RemoveDirectory(string path)
        {
            string filename = path;
            FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + _Host + path);
            ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_UserName, _Password);
            ftpRequest.EnableSsl = _UseSSL;
            ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.RemoveDirectory;

            FtpWebResponse ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
            ftpResponse.Close();
        }
    }

    //Для парсинга полученного детального списка каталогов фтп-сервера
    //Структура для хранения детальной информации о файле или каталоге
    public struct FileStruct
    {
        public string Flags;
        public string Owner;
        public bool IsDirectory;
        public string CreateTime;
        public string Name;
    }

    public enum FileListStyle
    {
        UnixStyle,
        WindowsStyle,
        Unknown
    }

    //Класс для парсинга
    public class DirectoryListParser
    {
        private List<FileStruct> _myListArray;

        public FileStruct[] FullListing
        {
            get
            {
                return _myListArray.ToArray();
            }
        }

        public FileStruct[] FileList
        {
            get
            {
                List<FileStruct> _fileList = new List<FileStruct>();
                foreach (FileStruct thisstruct in _myListArray)
                {
                    if (!thisstruct.IsDirectory)
                    {
                        _fileList.Add(thisstruct);
                    }
                }
                return _fileList.ToArray();
            }
        }

        public FileStruct[] DirectoryList
        {
            get
            {
                List<FileStruct> _dirList = new List<FileStruct>();
                foreach (FileStruct thisstruct in _myListArray)
                {
                    if (thisstruct.IsDirectory)
                    {
                        _dirList.Add(thisstruct);
                    }
                }
                return _dirList.ToArray();
            }
        }

        public DirectoryListParser(string responseString)
        {
            _myListArray = GetList(responseString);
        }

        private List<FileStruct> GetList(string datastring)
        {
            List<FileStruct> myListArray = new List<FileStruct>();
            string[] dataRecords = datastring.Split('\n');
            //Получаем стиль записей на сервере
            FileListStyle _directoryListStyle = GuessFileListStyle(dataRecords);
            foreach (string s in dataRecords)
            {
                if (_directoryListStyle != FileListStyle.Unknown && s != "")
                {
                    FileStruct f = new FileStruct();
                    f.Name = "..";
                    switch (_directoryListStyle)
                    {
                        case FileListStyle.UnixStyle:
                            f = ParseFileStructFromUnixStyleRecord(s);
                            break;

                        case FileListStyle.WindowsStyle:
                            f = ParseFileStructFromWindowsStyleRecord(s);
                            break;
                    }
                    if (f.Name != "" && f.Name != "." && f.Name != "..")
                    {
                        myListArray.Add(f);
                    }
                }
            }
            return myListArray;
        }

        //Парсинг, если фтп сервера работает на Windows
        private FileStruct ParseFileStructFromWindowsStyleRecord(string Record)
        {
            //Предположим стиль записи 02-03-04  07:46PM       <DIR>     Append
            FileStruct f = new FileStruct();
            string processstr = Record.Trim();
            //Получаем дату
            string dateStr = processstr.Substring(0, 8);
            processstr = (processstr.Substring(8, processstr.Length - 8)).Trim();
            //Получаем время
            string timeStr = processstr.Substring(0, 7);
            processstr = (processstr.Substring(7, processstr.Length - 7)).Trim();
            f.CreateTime = dateStr + " " + timeStr;
            //Это папка или нет
            if (processstr.Substring(0, 5) == "<DIR>")
            {
                f.IsDirectory = true;
                processstr = (processstr.Substring(5, processstr.Length - 5)).Trim();
            }
            else
            {
                string[] strs = processstr.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                processstr = strs[1];
                f.IsDirectory = false;
            }
            //Остальное содержмое строки представляет имя каталога/файла
            f.Name = processstr;
            return f;
        }

        //Получаем на какой ОС работает фтп-сервер - от этого будет зависеть дальнейший парсинг
        public FileListStyle GuessFileListStyle(string[] recordList)
        {
            foreach (string s in recordList)
            {
                //Если соблюдено условие, то используется стиль Unix
                if (s.Length > 10
                    && Regex.IsMatch(s.Substring(0, 10), "(-|d)((-|r)(-|w)(-|x)){3}"))
                {
                    return FileListStyle.UnixStyle;
                }
                //Иначе стиль Windows
                else if (s.Length > 8
                    && Regex.IsMatch(s.Substring(0, 8), "[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}"))
                {
                    return FileListStyle.WindowsStyle;
                }
            }
            return FileListStyle.Unknown;
        }

        //Если сервер работает на nix-ах
        private FileStruct ParseFileStructFromUnixStyleRecord(string record)
        {
            //Предположим. тчо запись имеет формат dr-xr-xr-x   1 owner    group    0 Nov 25  2002 bussys
            FileStruct f = new FileStruct();
            if (record[0] == '-' || record[0] == 'd')
            {// правильная запись файла
                string processstr = record.Trim();
                f.Flags = processstr.Substring(0, 9);
                f.IsDirectory = (f.Flags[0] == 'd');
                processstr = (processstr.Substring(11)).Trim();
                //отсекаем часть строки
                _cutSubstringFromStringWithTrim(ref processstr, ' ', 0);
                f.Owner = _cutSubstringFromStringWithTrim(ref processstr, ' ', 0);
                f.CreateTime = getCreateTimeString(record);
                //Индекс начала имени файла
                int fileNameIndex = record.IndexOf(f.CreateTime) + f.CreateTime.Length;
                //Само имя файла
                f.Name = record.Substring(fileNameIndex).Trim();
            }
            else
            {
                f.Name = "";
            }
            return f;
        }

        private string getCreateTimeString(string record)
        {
            //Получаем время
            string month = "(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)";
            string space = @"(\040)+";
            string day = "([0-9]|[1-3][0-9])";
            string year = "[1-2][0-9]{3}";
            string time = "[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}";
            Regex dateTimeRegex = new Regex(month + space + day + space + "(" + year + "|" + time + ")", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            Match match = dateTimeRegex.Match(record);
            return match.Value;
        }

        private string _cutSubstringFromStringWithTrim(ref string s, char c, int startIndex)
        {
            int pos1 = s.IndexOf(c, startIndex);
            string retString = s.Substring(0, pos1);
            s = (s.Substring(pos1)).Trim();
            return retString;
        }
    }
}
```

and this void

```
//Построение дерева файловой системы ftp сервера 
private static void ListDirectory(TreeView treeView, string Host, string UserName, string password)
{
    Ftp_Client ftp = new Ftp_Client();
    ftp.Host = Host;
    ftp.UserName = UserName;
    ftp.Password = password;
    treeView.Nodes.Clear();

    var stack = new Stack<TreeNode>();
    var rootDirectory = DOMAIN;
    var node = new TreeNode(rootDirectory) { Tag = "/" };
    stack.Push(node);

    while (stack.Count > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            var currentNode = stack.Pop();
            var directoryInfo = ftp.ListDirectory((string)currentNode.Tag);
            foreach (var directory in directoryInfo)
            {
                if (directory.IsDirectory && directory.Name!="?") {
                    var childDirectoryNode = new TreeNode(directory.Name) { Tag = currentNode.Tag+directory.Name+'/'};
                    currentNode.Nodes.Add(childDirectoryNode);
                    stack.Push(childDirectoryNode);
                }
            }
            foreach (var file in directoryInfo)
                if (!file.IsDirectory && file.Name != "?")
                    currentNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(file.Name) { Tag = currentNode.Tag + file.Name + "/f"}); ; //пометка f в конце пути означает, что это файл!
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    treeView.Nodes.Add(node);
}
```

calling by

```
ListDirectory(treeView1,DOMAIN,USER,PASS);
```